# Visual Studio 2017 ASP.Net Core Angular project not working after upgrading to Angular 5

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017

I've successfully upgraded an empty project to use Angular 5 by following [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1221503/Angular-and-NET-Core-with-Visual-Studio).  I'm not using the `IIS` part as I'm testing locally with `IIS Express`.

However, when I start the app, I just see the text `Loading...` in the page and nothing else.

The article says that I need to change this:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

with:

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

in `Views/Home/Index.cshtml`.

Is this correct? Could the problem be somewhere else?

**EDIT**

I'm getting the following error in Chrome:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "@angular/common/http"
>       at Object. (main-client.jsv=SR1R2f9X17xMnMEfwymdHMp2ZbAGWFRSTzfxf80cmgg:1394)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cecf12e96da858d1e568:19)
>       at Object.hasOwn (css-base.js:76)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cecf12e96da858d1e568:19)
>       at Object. (navmenu.component.ts:8)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap cecf12e96da858d1e568:19)
>       at module.exports (bootstrap cecf12e96da858d1e568:65)
>       at bootstrap cecf12e96da858d1e568:65

When doing `npm install` I get the following error:

> 22821 verbose stack Error: AboFlex@0.0.0 postinstall: `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`
>   22821 verbose stack Exit status 1
>   22821 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
>   22821 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
>   22821 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   22821 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>   22821 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
>   22821 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)

Comment: No errors in the console?

Comment: @Carsten None. Rebuild All succeeded.

Comment: I assume he meant the browser console. When you only see "Loading..." it means the Angular app is not loaded so you should see some errors there.

Comment: Do you write: webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js to refresh the vendor? What is the version of angular in your package.json?

Comment: @Eliseo Yes. I write that in the scripts section of package.json. The angular version is now 5.2.10

Comment: I just follow the instructions of the article and work for me. My version is Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.4.4, Microsoft .NET FrameWork 4.7.02556. Try repeat all the steps (be sure the directory where you're execute the command is the same directory where is your package.json file) and that you haven't any package.json in child or child/child directory and don't execute until you completed all them :(